# Creating an alternative registration action in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

I have a working registration and sign in process using Devise & Rails 4. However I've also created an Invitation system, where existing users can invite others to join their organisation. For this reason I want a new page where both a signup and registration form lie, so that when they click on their invitation link (which looks like: /register_from_invitation/TOKEN_HERE), they will be able to sign up to accept the invite, or if they already have an account, login to accept.

So in my routes I have:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {
  :sessions => "sessions",
  :registrations => "registrations",
  :confirmations => "confirmations",
  :passwords => "passwords"
}

devise_scope :user do
  get "register_from_invitation/:token", to: "registrations#new_from_invitation", as: "register_from_invitation"
  post "register_from_invitation/:token", to: "registrations#create_from_invitation", as: "create_registration_from_invitation"
  post "sign_in_from_invitation/:token", to: "sessions#create_from_invitation", as: "sign_in_from_invitation"
end
```

I'll concentrate on the RegistrationsController. As well as the "normal" `new` and `create` methods it has two others (modelled closely on the originals) to respond to the above routes:

```
def new_from_invitation
  @invitation = Invitation.where(token: params[:token]).first
  build_resource({})
  self.resource.organisations << @invitation.organisation
  respond_with self.resource
end

def create_from_invitation
  @invitation = Invitation.where(token: params[:token]).first
  build_resource(sign_up_params)

  if resource.save
    resource.organisations << @invitation.organisation
    resource.roles[0].roles << @invitation.role.to_sym
    resource.roles[0].save
    @invitation.destroy
    SignupNotificationMailer.signup_notification_email(resource).deliver
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
      sign_up(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, :location => '/users/sign_up'
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
      expire_data_after_sign_in!
      respond_with resource, :location => '/users/sign_up'
    end
  else
    clean_up_passwords resource
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

When I hit the register button without a properly completed form I am hoping for it to go back to exactly the same page, with the same url (/register_from_invitation/TOKEN_HERE), but instead I get the `new` action being shown. If I change the last `respond_with resource` to:

```
respond_with resource, action: new_from_invitation
```

... which I would think should work, I get an error: `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.`

How can I get this new registration cycle to only redirect and render using the *_from_invitation routes and methods? The same will apply to the sign_in_from_invitation route later on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned respond_with and am now just doing:

```
render "new_from_invitation"
```

It works fine.